# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, vision-api

**help me this a simple script to implement google vision API in python .

### i installed all requirements i need but still see that error**

### AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Client'

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/TAKWA/Desktop/vision/44.py", line 4, in 
>       vision_client = vision.Client() AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Client'

---

```
import io
from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.Client('my-key')
file_name = '1.jpg'

with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    image = vision_client.image(
        content=content, )

labels = image.detect_labels()
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Answer (score 2):

`vision_client = vision.Client('my-key')`

Should be

`vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()`

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library